# How to run a minified Express.js server

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a minified Express.js project in the 'dist' folder.
Grunt uglifies the entire 'dist' folder and places the results in a 'build' folder.
Up to this point everything is fine. But, nothing runs afterwards without manually copying the 'package.json' file and then running `npm install`.
All I get is `Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'` .

Am I missing something here?
Does a minified Express server suppose to run differently?
Or are my configurations faulty?
The Gruntfile is as follows -

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    const folder = 'some/path';
    grunt.initConfig({

    uglify: {
        files: { 
            src: 'dist/**/*.js',
            dest: folder,
            expand: true,
            flatten: false,
            ext: '.min.js'
        },
    },
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

};
```

Edit:
package.json -

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "main": "src/ser.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Someone",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.28.0",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "grunt": "^1.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you also provide you package.json file?

Comment: @MbulaMbomaJeangilbert - In 'dist' the files are already js files, and they are indeed minified in 'build'. The question is how to run them then.

Comment: You can run your minified files by running `node minifiedfolder/ser.min.js`

Comment: do you have any feedback?

Comment: @MbulaMbomaJeangilbert - Thanks, but the error I get when I do that is Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'.

Comment: @O.K. can your please tell me how you minified you expres.js code? I was searching for how to minify express.js code, I came here. but you haven't mentioned how you minified it.
Thank you in advance.